# Python Celery tasks not being processed

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery

I'm trying to get Celery working with Python 3.6 on my Windows machine using
Redis as my message broker. However, I find that only about half of my tasks are getting executed. The remaining tasks never get processed.

To help debug this problem I have created a simple task which just
waits for 5 seconds and then writes to a file:

```py
@capp.task
def test(inputs):

    print('Entering function Test for simulation: ' + inputs['simulation'])
    time.sleep(5)

    fout = open(inputs['results_path'] + inputs['simulation'], 'w')
    fout.write("Test\n")
    fout.close()

    return 0.0
```

where I'm calling the above as follows:

```py
    inputs_array = []
    inputs_array.append({'simulation':'Test1','results_path':results_path})
    inputs_array.append({'simulation':'Test2','results_path':results_path})
    inputs_array.append({'simulation':'Test3','results_path':results_path})
    inputs_array.append({'simulation':'Test4','results_path':results_path})

    print("Entering the Test simulation: ")
    tasks = []

    for inputs in inputs_array:
        task = vmlvsv.app_test.test.apply_async((inputs,), compression='zlib')
        tasks.append(task)
```

Based on advice I have used the following celeryconfig settings:

CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1

However, only a subset of the four tasks above are ever executed (usually just 2 and sometimes 3)?

I'm using celery (3.1.25) and redis (2.10.6) where celery 
is called as follows:
celery worker -A mp_app.capp --loglevel=debug

Any advice would be welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: you can install flower
https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
and then debug task queue 

maybe you will find missed tasks in REVOKED state

Comment: Try to run `celery -A my_app.capp events` to see what is going on. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#celery-events-curses-monitor